# syncing is never finish on geth fast

Tags: go-ethereum, fast-sync

I have run geth --fast --cache=4000 for 8 days and I think I am almost complete:

```
eth.syncing {   
currentBlock: 8123223,   
highestBlock: 8123315,   
knownStates: 309587058,   
pulledStates: 309573531,   
startingBlock:    > 8123170 
}
```

geth is import state entries only.

my timedatectl output is:

```
                      Local time: Wed 2019-07-10 11:49:05 UTC
                  Universal time: Wed 2019-07-10 11:49:05 UTC
                        RTC time: Wed 2019-07-10 11:49:06
                       Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

What should I do?

Comment: Most likely your hardware is too slow so you will never get synchronized. If you're using HDD then you have to switch to SDD

Comment: i use digitalocean block storage(ssd).

Comment: is there and advice?